# CakePHP passing data to element

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code in my controller:

```
function index()
{
    $posts = $this->set('posts', $this->Portfolio->find('all'));

    if (isset($this->params['requested']))
    {
        return $posts;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Portfolio->find('all'));
    }
}
```

and what I want it to do is a) show a list of portfolio items for the index e.g. `/portfolio/` and b) show a list of portfolio items inside an element so a user can access the portfolio items from my sidebar across the site.

Here is my element for the sidebar:

```
<?php $posts = $this->requestAction('portfolio/index'); ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Portfolio']['title'], array('action' => 'view', $post['Portfolio']['id']));?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

and then I call it like so in my layout:

```
<?php $this->element('portfolio-nav', array('posts' => $posts) ); ?>
```

However it gives the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: posts [APP/controllers/portfolio_controller.php, line 16]
```

And doesn't show the list of items in the sidebar.

I'm pretty sure what I have written in my controller is garbage, so if anyone can help me get it working, that'd be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 32):

I answered the very same question yesterday. Why is your controller action so complex? I guess you don't need anything more than

```
function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Portfolio->find('all'));
    // Make sure the model Portfolio is accessible from here, i.e. place this
    // action in PortfoliosController or load it using 
    // ClassRegistry::init('Portfolio')->find... 
}
```

Then, in your index.ctp view:

```
<?php echo $this->element('foobar', array('posts' => $posts)); ?>
```

If you want to be able to request this from every page in your site (sidebar or something), you can use `requestAction`, or place the `$this->set...` in your AppController. If you use `requestAction` in your element, you don't have to pass `array('posts' => ...)` in your `$this->element` call.

---

Ok, It's clear you need much more direction. Let me explain this step by step. First we need to create a `beforeFilter` on your `AppController`, so the `$posts` variable is accessible from everywhere in your application.

`/app/app_controller.php`:

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->set('posts', ClassRegistry::init('Portfolio')->find('all'));
    }
}
```

Next, we're creating a simple element in `app/views/elements/foobar.ctp`:

```
<?php debug($items); ?>
```

Lastly, we call the element from somewhere in a view:

```
<?php echo $this->element('foobar', array('items' => $posts)); ?>
```

We are assigning the $posts (which we have defined in your AppController) variable the `items` key, because our element expects a `$items` variable.

Comment: That was my point though I NEED to request this from every page but it doesn't work it just says the $posts variable is undefined!

Comment: Done what you have said but on portfolio the element is empty and when viewing other pages it throws an error saying posts is undefined.

Comment: Doesn't work when viewing a single item though: http://driz.co.uk/cake/portfolio/view/2 complains about `Notice (8): Undefined index:  Portfolio [APP/views/elements/portfolio-nav.ctp, line 3]` any ideas what the problem is? This is line 3 : `<li><?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Portfolio']['title'], array('controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'view', $post['Portfolio']['id']));?></li>`

Comment: Do a debug on `$post`, i.e. `debug($post)` so you can see what's inside. Are you sure you didn't overwrite the `$post`/`$posts` variable? This is very basic stuff.

Comment: Where do I do the debug? it may be basic to you but this is very complicated to me.

Comment: You place `debug($post);` in your element, that's where you actually call `$post`, right? (set it at line 2, just before your $this->Html... call)

Answer (score 8):

The second argument in the element method passes data. What you need is:

```
$this->element('portfolio-nav', array('posts' => $posts) );
```

Please read the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements).

Comment: Put the line that defines $posts outside of the element.

Comment: The portfolio index works fine. But the sidebar list doesn't!

Comment: If I'm honest I'm struggling to work out why you are using the request action at all. You shouldn't use a controller to pull up content for another page.. Just put it in your layout/app_controller?

Comment: This is the right answer. Following this method, access the data you pass through as such: $posts.

Comment: Worked very well for me.

Answer (score 5):

Element with param

```
$this->element('elementname', array('var_name'=>$var));
```

Comment: Can you give any example?

Answer (score 2):

One thing I don't think has been picked up on, your error message:

`Notice (8): Undefined variable: posts [APP/controllers/portfolio_controller.php, line 16]`

is in the controller. What you have posted looks okay (though slightly verbose code), so I would be asking where is line 16 in PortfolioController and why is $posts not defined?

Returning a value from a controller to use in the element works in general so no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the $posts var in the element and trying to pass it from the layout to the element o.o

your code is going in this order

```
render layout
include element passing variable
set var with requestAction
```

foreach

you should be doing

```
render layout
include element (dont pass anything)
set var with requesAction (you get the data here so why are you trying to pass it in)
```

Comment: your answer was a long winded rewrite your code and put it in app_controller, mine was stop passing uninitialized variables that are being initialized in the element anyhow...

Comment: "If you use requestAction in your element, you don't have to pass array('posts' => ...) in your $this->element call."

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if it works or not ..

I made some changes to your Controller::index() function :

```
function index () {
    // this is the problem
    // $posts = $this->set('posts', $this->Portfolio->find('all'));

    $posts = $this->Portfolio->find ( 'all' );

    if (isset($this->params['requested']))
    {
        return $posts;
    }
    else
    {
        // you already have the posts
        //$this->set('posts', $this->Portfolio->find('all'));

        $this->set ( 'posts', $posts );
    }
}
```

no changes to your element `portfolio-nav`..

change the call in your layout to become :

```
<?php $this->element ( 'portfolio-nav' ); ?>
```

I hope this was helpful for you..
good luck with your development..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way as well.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $var;    

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
         $this->var = ClassRegistry::init('Portfolio')->find('all');
    }
 }
class YourController extends AppController {

    public function index() {

        debug($this->var);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this very simply:

**controller:**

```
function birdsTwo() { 
    return $this->Bird->find('all', array('order' => 'Bird.name ASC', 'limit' => 2));   
}
```

**layout:**

```
<?php echo $this->element('quick_5_birds'); ?>
```

**element:**

```
$birds = $this->requestAction('/birds/birdsTwo/');
    foreach($birds as $bird) {
          echo $this->Html->link(__($bird['Bird']['name'], true), 
array('controller' =>'bird','action' => 'view', $bird['Bird']['id'])) . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View Cakephp Documentation
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

```
echo $this->element('helpbox', array(
    "helptext" => "Oh, this text is very helpful."
));
```

If you need the variable in every view, you should set it in the session.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Controller users
public function getUsers(){

     $users=  $this->User->find("all");

     return $users;
    }


//Element name users

$this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'getUsers'))

//vista name view
 print_r( $this->element('users')); ?>
```