# How to get controller view inside an element?

Tags: cakephp

I have created an element having a text field(Status Bar same as Facebook) which i extended in home/display view.

Code for element:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->css('notes'); 
echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery','jquery.elastic','notes'));
?>
<div class="notescontainer">
<div class="share">Share:</div>
<div class="notes">Notes</div>
<div class="loading"></div>
<div class="img_top"></div>
<div class="text_status">

<?php 
echo $this->form->create('Note', array('action' => 'notes'));
echo $this->form->input('notes',array('class' => 'notesbar', 'label'=>'', 'placeholder' => 'Write down you notes ...'));
?>
</div>
<div class="button_outside_border" id="share">
<div class="button_inside_border">

<?php 
echo $this->form->submit('Share',array('alt' => 'Add', 'class' => 'sharebutton'));
echo $this->form->end();
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="load_status_out"></div>
</div>
```

I want that when user shares the status it should re-appear on the same page that is display/home and for that i created a controller for retrieving the status entered by the user.

Controller:

```
<?php public function notes()
{
$this->set('allnotes', $this->Note->find('all'));
}?>
```

Controller View:

```
<?php 

foreach($allnotes as $viewnotes):
{

    echo $viewnotes['Note']['notes']; 
    echo "<br>";
}
endforeach;
?>
```

Now i want this controller view to be displayed on home/display view. Is there any way i can extend it in that element? I don`t want to add it directly on my home/display view as it already fully loaded.

Comment: As @sibidiba suggested, you can use elements and pass the variable for loop to element. Might wanna check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523162/cakephp-passing-data-to-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [requestAction()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction) to accomplish this, but in my experience it is buggy and a sign of design failure if you need it.
Alternatively you can turn all your view into elements, which can be embedded in each other in any arbitrary way. Then you can just call some shared code in the controller to populate all required models.

Comment: How can i make the controller view to element ... seems impossible as i added loop that includes a variable that stores data from the controller.