# CakePHP - Submenu in a different element

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I have a question about building a submenu. In my layout, not in a view, I got two elements. The first element is the main menu and the second element is the submenu. Its not that kind of a submenu when you hoover over a button from the main menu a magical submenu appears under the main menu.

I understand how to build a dynamic main menu in CakePHP. `Model-Controller->View->Element->Layout`. But when Im using this same approuch for my submenu, my submenu will be static. Because when Im pressing on a button the content is changing (view) and not the layout.

Which solutions are there to change the submenu to the corresponding pressed button on the main menu?

**Controller/MenuController.php**

```
class MenusController extends AppController{

var $name = 'Menus';

function main() {
    if (isset($this->params['requested']) && $this->params['requested'] == true) {

        $menus = $this->Menu->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array('Menu.parent_id' => '0'), array ('order' => 'position')));

        return $menus;
    } else {
        $this->set('menus', $this->Menu->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array('Menu.parent_id' => '0'), array ('order' => 'position'))));
    }
}

function sub() {
    if (isset($this->params['requested']) && $this->params['requested'] == true) {

        $subs = $this->Menu->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array('Menu.parent_id' => '1'), array ('order' => 'position')));

        return $subs;
   // } else {
     //   $this->set('subs', $this->Menu->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array('Menu.controller' => $this->params['controller']), array ('order' => 'position'))));
    }


    //debug($this->params['controller']);
}  
}
```

**Model/Menu.php**

```
class Menu extends AppModel {    
    var $name = 'Menu';    
}
```

**View/Layouts/Default.ctp**

```
<div id="submenu">                    
     <?php echo $this->element('main'); ?>                   
     <?php echo $this->element('sub'); ?>                    
</div>
```

### Edited

I tried to build a query for the submenu. The plain string does work. When I request the controller name and use it in the query it doesnt work. With debug($this->request['controller']) I get and see the controller name.  But why doesnt this work in a query?

```
 function sub() {
 // $subrequest = "Projects";
 $subrequest = $this->request['controller'];

 if (isset($this->params['requested']) && $this->params['requested'] == true) {
    $subs = $this->Menu->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array('Menu.controller' => $subrequest)));
    return $subs;
 } else {
     $this->set('subs', $this->Menu->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array('Menu.controller' => $subrequest))));
 }
}
```

Comment: can you provide code pplease.

Answer (score 0):

The entire layout and view is rendered on each page load. You don't need your MenuController. You will need to set the `$menus` and `$subs` variables in `AppController->beforeFilter` method where you can detect what controller you are in and what action. Make sure every controller extends AppController and calls its `parent::beforeFiler`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will now look into it.

Comment: So if I change the view the layout itself will also render?

Comment: Yes, every time a page is loaded, CakePHP parses the elements and the views, then integrates them into the layout and then outputs the page. In practice the layout should contain the header and the footer of the page and a view should be the content.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Than i have another question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time.

The answer in my topic and this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523162/cakephp-passing-data-to-element) gave me the final solution.

**So What did I do?**

1. I removed the menuController
2. I made a beforeFilter in the appController and pass the vars to the the elements main and
       sub.