# CakePHP - Passing a variable from a controller to the layout using an element

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHP version: 2.6.

I'm trying to pass a variable from my PostsController to my layout using an element. What I want to do is to show the total number of posts awaiting approval in my header.

I have the following code in my PostsController.php (abbreviated version):

```
function admin_validation() {

    $nbr_validate = $this->Post->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Post.validation = 0'
        )
    ));

    $this->set('nbr_validate', $nbr_validate);
}
```

I call it in my layout (admin.ctp):

```
<?php echo $this->element('posts-validation', array('nbr_validate' => $nbr_validate)); ?>
```

Here's my element (posts-validation.ctp):

```
<?php echo $nbr_validate; ?>
```

I get the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: nbr_validate [APP/View/Layouts/admin.ctp, line 54]
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: Check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523162/cakephp-passing-data-to-element and answer that have 14 reputation

Comment: It's been a while since I've used CakePHP, but from what I remember, it looks like you're doing everything correctly.  Just a shot in the dark: what happens if you hard code a number in your `admin_validation` function like `$this->set('nbr_validate', 10);`

Comment: OK after looking at your code for a bit longer, I retract my previous statement.  If you are calling `$this->set('nbr_validate', $nbr_validate);` in the `admin_validation function`, then the `$nbr_validate` variable will only be available in the `admin_validation.ctp` layout file (unless you have omitted a call to `$this->render('admin');`).

Comment: I found the solution on the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523162/cakephp-passing-data-to-element Thank you for replying!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this very simply:

**AppController:**

```
$this->set('nbr_validate', ClassRegistry::init('Post')->find('count', 
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'validation = 0'
        )
    )
));
```

**Element:**

```
<?php echo $nbr_validate; ?>
```

**View:**

```
<?php echo $this->element('posts-validation', array('nbr_validate' => $nbr_validate)); ?>
```